# undefined reference to `_imp__gsl_version'

Tags: c++, mingw, gsl

I have just finished compiling and installing gtk+ (2.24.10) gtkmm(2.17.2) gtkglext(1.2.0) and gsl(1.8) (and all the required dependencies) in windows using MinGW which are dependencies for the software MRtrix. 
Now however,  when I try to build MRtrix with the script: http://pastebin.com/XnufSz53

I get an `undefined reference to`*imp*_gsl_version'` the whole error is pasted bellow.

from app.cpp which I have pasted here: http://pastebin.com/dDtKEYk1

Is there something going wrong with the installation of gsl? How can I find out more information about what is going wrong?

Thank you very much
Jesse

```
g++ -shared lib\image\format\base.o lib\math\vector.o lib\file\mmap.o lib\args.o
 lib\image\format\dicom.o lib\file\dicom\select_cmdline.o lib\file\key_value.o l
ib\image\axis.o lib\image\format\mrtrix.o lib\image\interp.o lib\data_type.o lib
\point.o lib\image\mapper.o lib\file\dicom\element.o lib\file\dicom\mapper.o lib
\file\dicom\patient.o lib\file\dicom\quick_scan.o lib\image\object.o lib\mrtrix.
o lib\image\format\xds.o lib\file\dicom\dict.o lib\app.o lib\math\matrix.o lib\f
ile\config.o lib\image\format\mri.o lib\file\dicom\image.o lib\math\linalg.o lib
\file\dicom\study.o lib\file\dicom\series.o lib\image\name_parser.o lib\image\fo
rmat\list.o lib\file\dicom\tree.o lib\image\fft.o lib\image\header.o lib\image\f
ormat\analyse.o lib\image\format\nifti1.o -LC:/MinGW/lib -lglibmm-2.4 -lgobject-
2.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lgsl -lgslcblas -lz -o lib\mrtri
x-0_2_11.dll

failed with output:

lib\app.o:app.cpp:(.text+0x3396): undefined reference to `_imp__gsl_version'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Run `nm libgsl.a`, and see if `_imp__gsl_version` symbol is there.

Comment: under `version.o:` I find `_gsl_version` but no `_imp__gsl_version`

Comment: Seems like something might be mixed up about whether a static or DLL version of the gsl library should be used.

Comment: from the site http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm "If you will be using one of the dynamic libraries, add GSL_DLL to the list of predefined macros; so for use with Mingw / GCC, add -DGSL_DLL " is -DGSL_DLL a comand line option? it does not work with ./configure. How do I compile and install gsl with the dynamic libraries?